# Nginx reverse proxy doesn't allow POST requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx

I have a server on which I serve my 2 Node js apps, one on https://example.com/app1 and another one on https://example.com/app2. I managed to get this working by using nginx reverse proxy, setting each app to run on one port, and redirecting clients to each port based on the above addresses.

However, I'm facing this problem now where I can't save any POST requests to my MongoDB. Specifically, if I make POST request from https://example.com/app1 I get 405; if I send POST request from https://example.com:3000 everything is fine and data is saved in DB. Just to make it clear, port 3000 is the port on which app1 is running.
Can someone help me and point out to me what am I missing here? I feel like the issue here is that the app is working on port 3000 and is shown on port 80, but the data from port 80 doesn't get back to port 3000?

My reverse proxy code:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mysubdomain.domain.com www.mysubdomain.domain.com;

        location /app1 {
        rewrite ^/app1/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://myIPaddress:3000;
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't know nginx well enough to know what the right syntax is, but I suspect you are telling the client to redirect rather than directly forwarding requests and browser clients don't redirect POST requests.  You can confirm this by opening the network tab in the Chrome debugger and see if you are getting a 3xx response back from the POST.

Comment: @jfriend00 it was 405. I believe I managed to solve this by changing the path in fetch() to fetch('/app1/', data). I would still like to know if there is nginx solution for this.